# Passing domain name to PayPal

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to sell something to domain owners. I need to know their domain names. Before the payment procedure I'll ask their domain names in my web site, I'll store the data in the cookies or the url, then I want to pass the data (domain name) to the PayPal so that I'll know who paid for what domain name.
I know PHP and HTML in advanced level but I don't know how to pass the data to PayPal. How I'll do that?
And will I be able to see that data in my PayPal page?
And what should I name the input tag?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are custom HTML transaction variables that can be set for things like this and you will have to name the input tag accordingly. There would be two input elements for each custom field that you want to save. One for the field name and one for the field value.

These tags are **on0**, **on1**, or **on2** for the custom field names and **os0**, **os1**, and **os2** for the custom field values.

Im pretty sure you can see these values from the transaction details page while viewing your account but Im not 100%.

[Here's the info on PayPal's HTML parameters](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to start by reading the [Paypal developer documentation](https://www.paypal.com/documentation). You will probably find their "standard website payments" option will do what you want, but it's been a long time since I've looked at the different options, so worth looking around!